# Xpath query returns no element found

Tags: regex, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm querying google search for number of searches. the xpath query i'm using is `//div[@id='resultStats']` which too my understanding on the pages html:

```
<div id="resultStats">About 1,660,000,000 results<nobr> (0.65 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

should return the data within the div.

I've tried with `Importhtml(url,xpath)` and http://xpather.com/ <- an XML path tester and I get "Imported content is empty" and "no content found" respectively.

I was initially using `importhtml` and isolated the issue to the XPath using xpather as an XPath tester, so I think I've zoned the issue down a bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(MID(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1&"";"table";1);4;2);6;23);"\D+";))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I was meant to be asking for importxml hence my xpath being the way it was. Thanks for tidying up the question.